# Pull the new data from website into the existing table with Scrapy

Tags: python, mysql, sql, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a Scrapy project with Python. I pulled all data from website that I want. But I want to pull new data from website into the existing table instead of pulling the data from the beginning at each update. For example,

```
+---------------------------+
| ID  |  Name   |   Job     |
+---------------------------+
| 01  |  Maria  |   Doctor  |
+---------------------------+
| 02  |  Silvia |   Teacher |
+---------------------------+
| 03  |  Lora   |   Soldier |
+---------------------------+
```

With the new update, new data has been added to website. This data is:

```
+-------------------------+
| ID  | Name   | Job      |
+-------------------------+
| 04  | Blanca | Engineer |
+-------------------------+
```

So, when I run my code, I just want to pull the new data from website into the existing table. Not all over again.

How can I do it?

Comment: This sounds like `INSERT`.

Comment: Not actually. Yes, i used INSERT for pulling the all data. But i don't want to pull in all the data from beginning every time I run code. I just want to pull new data into my exists table when i run the code. So, INSERT isn't enough. Do you have another opinion on this subject? @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this is by using pipelines and mapping the data with previous one and inserting the record if it is not available already in the database. As far as the scrapy is concerned it is totally dependent on the selectors. if the selectors for the previous and the data on the site are the same then you can not differentiate the data while crawling it. The pipeline will help you to filter the records as per your requirements.

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I got it. But how can i code this in pipelines.py?

Comment: This will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43656127/scrapy-pipeline-doesnt-insert-into-mysql

Comment: Unfortunately i didn't understand it. Can you tell me which function I would use? My problem is: When I run the project, if there is a new data in website, the data should be added the exists table. Not all data. I just wanna add new data into my table.